# Passing data from one button click event to another button click event

Tags: c#, event-handling, buttonclick

Below is my code. I want to capture the difference between two timestamps at two different button clicks, i.e., i want the "startTime" of btnStartTime_click event to be used in btnEndTime_click event.

```
    protected void btnStartTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;            
        lblStartTime.Text = startTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");            
    }

    protected void btnEndTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        var workDuration = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalMinutes;
        lblEndTime.Text = ("The Work duration is "+workDuration);

    }
```

Comment: Is this for a client application or a web application?

Comment: Its a web appliaction....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this concerns a web application, you must store the `startTime` in a way where it can be restored on a later post back.

Here's a quick sample that should work using `ViewState`:

```
private const string StartTimeViewstateKey = "StartTimeViewstateKey";
protected void btnStartTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var startTime = DateTime.Now;
    ViewState[StartTimeViewstateKey] = startTime.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
protected void btnEndTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var startTime = DateTime.Parse((string)ViewState[StartTimeViewstateKey], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    var workDuration = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalMinutes;
    lblEndTime.Text = ("The Work duration is " + workDuration);
}
```

Alternatively you could use session state:

```
private const string StartTimeSessionKey= "StartTimeSessionKey";
protected void btnStartTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var startTime = DateTime.Now;
    Session[StartTimeSessionKey] = startTime;
}
protected void btnEndTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var startTime = (DateTime)Session[StartTimeSessionKey];

    var workDuration = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalMinutes;
    lblEndTime.Text = ("The Work duration is " + workDuration);
}
```

Comment: Hi **user1429080**, thanks for the reply. Found it very useful.

Answer (score 4):

Just make your `startTime` outside the local scope:

```
DateTime startTime;
protected void btnStartTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    startTime = DateTime.Now;            
    lblStartTime.Text = startTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");            
}

protected void btnEndTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    var workDuration = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalMinutes;
    lblEndTime.Text = ("The Work duration is "+workDuration);

}
```

Comment: Hi King, thanks for your response. But that didn't solve my problem. If I declare "startTime" outside and use it in btnEndTime_Click event, then I can't get the value of "startTime" captured in the btnStartTime_Click event. Instead, the value of startTime is taken as initial value, i.e., "01/01/0001 12:00 AM".

Comment: @Kash that's the default value, if you click the `btnEndTime` first that will happen, but normally you have to click on the `btnStartTime` first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I finally figured out why this was happening. Every time I clicked on the **btnEndTime**, the page was posting back. So I always had the default value in that variable. I just changed the declaration as static and every thing was fine.

Comment: @Kash Please keep in mind that if you use this solution and make the `startTime` static, then ALL USERS of your web site will use the same `startTime`. If user A clicks start, then user B clicks start 2 minuter later, and then user A clicks end, A will see the start time from user B. Do not use static variables in web pages unless you are really sure of what you are doing.